# Move 5 columns from one sheet to another but place into one row

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 columns in a data source that I need to pull:
`Line1|Line2|Line3|Line4|Line5`

...all with data under them. I need to pull those 5 columns into a new sheet and not only rename them, but create more columns for each record.

Such as:
`shop1|add1|citystate1|phone1|web1|shop2|add2|citystate2|phone2|web2| etc.`

...with the data falling under the appropriate columns. The columns are the same only sequential for each record.

**Screen Shots**

The datasource image is what the data looks like now. Except that I copied these columns out of the original because there were other columns. I just need those 5 columns.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/0/view/vj1kgmzz6p44v4v/links/datasource.png]

The result image is how I need it to end up. There could be hundreds of records going across. The headers need to be sequential as shown. I have only included the first several columns but these extend horizontally several records.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/0/view/gu7x05nqncphl0b/links/result.png]

Comment: There's no private message functionality on SO, but you can leave a comment directing someone to the image.

Answer (score 0):

[image: moveShiftLaterally_before]
            <sup>Sample data</sup>

A long vertical list of contact information would be most expediently handled by direct value transfer.

```
Sub moveShiftLaterally_Values()
    Dim strHDR As String, rw As Long, cls As Long, vHDRs As Variant

    strHDR = "shop0|add0|citystate0|phone0|web0"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "horizList"

    With Worksheets("horizList")
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            'assign the correct increment and split the header string
            vHDRs = Split(Replace(strHDR, 0, rw - 1), Chr(124))
            'transfer the headers
            .Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, (rw - 2) * (UBound(vHDRs) + 1)).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1) = vHDRs
            'transfer the values
            .Cells(2, 1).Offset(0, (rw - 2) * (UBound(vHDRs) + 1)).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1) = _
                .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1).Value
        Next rw
        'remove the original entries
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 0).Clear
    End With

End Sub
```

[image: moveShiftLaterally_Values_after]
            <sup>After moveShiftLaterally_Values</sup>

However, with the possibility of custom number formatting for the phone numbers and varying column widths that should be homogenized horizontally, adding certain [XlPasteType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) facets of the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) to first seed the destination cells might ultimately prove to be the best method.

```
Sub moveShiftLaterally_All()
    Dim strHDR As String, rw As Long, cls As Long, vHDRs As Variant

    strHDR = "shop0|add0|citystate0|phone0|web0"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "horizList"

    With Worksheets("horizList")
        'seed the cell formats and column widths first
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(2, .Columns.Count)
                .Copy
                For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
                    'transfer the column widths and cell formatting
                    .Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, (rw - 2) * .Columns.Count).PasteSpecial _
                      Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                    .Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, (rw - 2) * .Columns.Count).PasteSpecial _
                      Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                Next rw
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
        End With
        'transfer the HDR and VALs
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            'assign the correct increment and split the header string
            vHDRs = Split(Replace(strHDR, 0, rw - 1), Chr(124))
            'transfer the headers
            .Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, (rw - 2) * (UBound(vHDRs) + 1)).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1) = vHDRs
            'transfer the values
            .Cells(2, 1).Offset(0, (rw - 2) * (UBound(vHDRs) + 1)).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1) = _
                .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1).Value
        Next rw
        'remove the original entries
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 0).Clear
    End With

End Sub
```

[image: moveShiftLaterally_All_after.]            <sup>After moveShiftLaterally_Values</sup>

I will leave it to you to decide which method suits your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The [Concatenate](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-HP005209020.aspx) function will probably do what you want.

Comment: I don't think this is what I want. As I said, I don't know much with Excel. What I'm seeing is Concatenate is for combining cells into one cell. I'm not wanting to combine anything. I just want to move the data to a new sheet but have it in one long row and the headers be different and sequential.

Comment: Are you looking for a transpose, then?